# Type of member is not CLS-compliant

Tags: asp.net, cls-compliant

Using Visual Studio 2008 and VB.Net:

I have a working web app that uses an ASMX web service which is compiled into its separate assembly. I have another class library project compiled as a separate assembly that serves as a proxy to this web service. This all seems to work at runtime but I am getting this warning at compile time which I don't understand and would like to fix:

**Type of member 'wsZipeee' is not CLS-compliant**

I have dozens of webforms in the main project that reference the proxy class with no compile time complaints as this snippet shows:

```
Imports System.Data
Partial Class frmZipeee
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public wsZipeee As New ProxyZipeeeService.WSZipeee.Zipeee
    Dim dsStandardMsg As DataSet

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
          Handles MyBase.Load
```

And yet I have one webform (also in the root of the main project) which gives me the "not CLS-compliant" message but yet attempts to reference the proxy class just like the other ASPX files. I get the compile time warning on the line annoted by me with 'ERROR here..

```
Imports System.Data
Partial Class frmHome
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public wsZipeee As New ProxyZipeeeService.WSZipeee.Zipeee   ERROR here 
    Dim dsStandardMsg As DataSet

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
         Handles MyBase.Load
```

This makes no sense to me. The file with the warning is called frmHome.aspx.vb; all others in the project declare things the same way and have no warning. BTW, the webservice itself returns standard datatypes: integer, string, and dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced this problem to the <%@ Page declarative of the "problem" file using `Codebehind` while the other file(s) used the `CodeFile` attribute. When I changed it, it triggered some new issues but I solved them and in turn the original complaint about nonCLScompliance went away.